# How can i use two cordova in same app

Tags: android, ios, cordova

Hello everybody i create application by jQuery mobile and 
i use cordova versions 6.3.0,
i have a problem because the plugin is use cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation needs version "6.3.0",
The problem is: i need push notification plugin com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin and it needs version "3.7.0" 
can use two cordova version On the same app ?.

Comment: Would it be possible to downgrade the plushplugin to a version number that is compatible with the oldest cordova version?

Comment: Can't you use this plugin? https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/ or is it the same? i use this one with the newest phonegap version